# hibernate cascade deletion

Tags: hibernate

i have one class called course and one class called tutorials
in class i hav set of tutorials .Wnen i delete course i want all tutorials associaed with that course to be deleted . But presently the tutorials are  not geting deleted when i delete the owner course only the foreign key courseid in tutorials tables becomes null;

i am using folloing code
 cascade="delete-orphan,all" inverse= "true" in course.hhm.xml

when i am deleting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
cascade="all-delete-orphan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "orphan" part doesn't have anything to do with cascading the deletion of a course to that of the tutorials, it allows

```
c.getTutorials().remove(tutorialToDelete);
session.merge( c );
```

to delete the tutorial that was removed in the collection instance, I don't know if there are performance issues associated with the orphan flag, but if you don't rely on that behavior you may just want to switch it to

```
cascade="delete"
```